# Angular 8 - How to add tenant name at the start of the route?

Tags: angular, routes

I am using angular 8 for my application. Since it is a multi-tenant application, I am trying to add tenant name in the route parameters like myapp.com/{tenant-name}/view?type=grid

if user hits wrong tenant name, I want show a 404 page.

I have AuthGuard in place to authenticate where it redirects to my oauth provider if the user isn't logged in.

How do I make this implementation? Any suggestions?

my current approutes are like this:

```
  [
    {
        path: '',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        redirectTo: '/view?type=grid'
    },
    {
        path: '',
        canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard],
        children: [
            {
                path: 'view',
                loadChildren: () => import('./+somemodule/somemodule.module').then(m => m.SomeModule)
            }
         // other sub lazy-loaded modules
          ]
    }
]
```